# Fill in the int array from zero to defined number

Tags: c++, arrays

i need to fill in the int[] array in C++ from zero to number defined by variable, but ISO C++ forbids variable length array...
How to easily fill in the array? Do i need to allocate/free the memory?

```
int possibilities[SIZE];
unsigned int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    possibilities[i] = i;
}
```

btw. if you would ask - Yes, i need exactly standard int[] arrays, no vectors, no maps etc.

Comment: Why exactly can't you use `std::vector`?

Comment: I need to pass the array to next_permutation()... And as i need it as easy as it could be, i don't want to build another own "permutation" function for vectors...

Comment: You know you can use vectors as a standard C array too? Just use int* array = &myvec[0]; and then array is usable as a standard array and will stay fixed unless you add any elements to the underlying vector

Comment: @JohnB: I actually didn't know that. :-)

Comment: @Radek, if you are talking about `std::next_permutation`, it doesn't need a C-style array, it works with bidirectional iterators, which vector will provide nicely (`begin()`, `end()`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you've found, you cannot create a variable-length array on the stack.  So your choices are either to allocate it on the heap (introduces memory-management issues), or to use a `std::vector` instead of a C-style array:

```
std::vector<int> possibilities(SIZE);
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    possibilities[i] = i;
}
```

If you want to get even more flashy, you can use STL to generate this sequence for you:

```
// This is a "functor", a class object that acts like a function with state
class IncrementingSequence
{
public:
    // Constructor, just set counter to 0
    IncrementingSequence() : i_(0) {}
    // Return an incrementing number
    int operator() () { return i_++; }
private:
    int i_;
}

std::vector<int> possibilities(SIZE);
// This calls IncrementingSequence::operator() for each element in the vector,
// and assigns the result to the element
std::generate(possibilities.begin(), possibilities.end(), IncrementingSequence);
```

Comment: nice one.  `generate_n` matches the requirement even closer.

Comment: @xtofl: In this case, I don't think it makes a great deal of difference.  The OP simply wants to fill the entire array/vector with an incrementing sequence.  As I understand it, `std::generate_n` is useful if you don't want to fill the entire thing.

Comment: In this solution is great elegance. I love it. :)

Comment: @Oli: I was referring to the fact that he uses an _array_, where the `begin()` and `end()` shim functions were absent before C++0x.  Then the pair `begin, SIZE` is more convenient to indicate a range.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth why not use `std::iota`?

Answer (score 32):

In c++11 you can use std::iota and std::array. Example below fills array sized 10 with values from 1 to 10.

```
std::array<int, 10> a;
std::iota(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);
```

**Edit**
Naturally std::iota works with vectors as well.

Comment: For those of you just finding this on google, std::iota is defined in header <numeric>

Comment: See also the [C++ reference page for `std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota).

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to boost then you already have access to an incrementing iterator.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

std::vector<int> possibilities(
    boost::counting_iterator<int>(0),
    boost::counting_iterator<int>(SIZE));
```

The [counting iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) essentially wraps incrementing a value.  So you can automatically tell it the begin and end values and vector will populate itself properly.

As mentioned elsewhere, the resulting vector can be used directly with std::next_permutation.

```
std::next_permutation(possibilities.begin(),possibilities.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<int> possibilities;
unsigned int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    possibilities.push_back(i);
}
```

Use `std::vector`(you need to include `<vector>`)

If you want pass vector to `std::next_permutation` you need to write:

```
std::next_permutation(possibilities.begin(),possibilities.end());
```

also you can use vector as C style arrays. `&vec[0]` returns pointer to C style array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `std::generate_n` function:

```
std::generate_n( myarray, SIZE, increment() );
```

Where `increment` is an object that generates numbers:

```
struct increment {
 int value;
 int operator() () { return ++value; }
 increment():value(0){}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make SIZE a constant (macro or `const`), you can use it to specify the size of your static array. If it is not possible to use a constant, for example you are reading the intended size from outside the program, then yes you will need to allocate the memory.

In short, if you don't know the size at compile time you probably need to allocate the memory at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

std::generate() can be used with a mutable lambda function to be more concise.  The following C++ snippet will place the values 0..9 inclusive in a vector A of size 10 and print these values on a single line of output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    size_t N = 10;
    vector<int> A(N);
    generate(A.begin(), A.end(), [i = 0]() mutable { return i++; });
    copy(A.begin(), A.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `SIZE` is a constant expression and you're allowed to use `std::array`, you can create a function template that will allow you to do this at **compile time**. Note from C++17, `std::array<T, N>::begin` is `constexpr` so that you can do all this at compile time.

##### C++17 Version

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> constexpr make_array()
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 8;
    //-------------------------------V-------->number of elements  
    constexpr auto arr  = make_array<SIZE>();
   

    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: arr)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; //prints 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 with newline in between
    }
    
}
```

[C++17 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PToaf35hd)

---

##### C++11 Version

But prior to C++17, `std::array<T, N>::begin` was not constexpr, we will need to modify the above example slightly for C++11 as shown below:

```
template<std::size_t N> std::array<int, N> make_array()
{
    std::array<int, N> tempArray{};
    int count = 0;
    for(int &elem:tempArray)
    {
        elem = ++count;
    }
    return tempArray;
}
int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 8;
    //---------------------VVVV---->number of elements  
    auto arr  = make_array<SIZE>();
   

    
    //lets confirm if all objects have the expected value 
    for(const auto &elem: arr)
    {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl; //prints 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 with newline in between
    }
    
}
```

[C++11 demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dKG3o1eq4)

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ 23, [`ranges::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/iota) can be used to initialize an array or other container with increasing values.

```cpp
#include <numeric>

// only used for output:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[5]; // also works the same for std::array<int, 5>, std::vector<int>, etc
    std::ranges::iota(arr, 0); // fills arr with increasing integers starting from 0
    std::ranges::copy(arr, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " ")); // 0 1 2 3 4 
}
```

Alternatively, since C++ 11, `std::begin` and `std::end` can be used to get iterators to plain arrays to pass to `std::iota`.

```cpp
#include <numeric> // for iota
#include <iterator> // for begin and end
#include <iostream> // output
int main() {
    int arr[5];
    std::iota(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 0);
    for (int x : arr) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use a dynamic arrays?

```
type * pointer;
pointer = new type[number_of_elements];

void main() 
{
int limit = 0; // Your lucky number
int * pointer = NULL; 
cout << "Please, enter limit number: ";           
cin >> n;
pointer = new int[limit+1]; // Just to be sure.
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
         pointer[i] = i; // Another way is: *(pointer+i) = i (correct me if I'm wrong)   
    }
delete [] pointer; // Free some memory
pointer = NULL; // If you are "pedant"
}
```

I don't pretend this is the best solution. I hope it helps.

Comment: Don't recommend `new[]` and `delete[]` to people who are new to C++.

Comment: Sorry, I think that std::vector<int> possibilities(SIZE); is more complex.

Comment: @rightfold see also the question; "i need exactly standard int[] arrays, no vectors, no maps etc."

Answer (score -2):

it should be help u man

```
int* a = NULL;   // Pointer to int, initialize to nothing.
int n;           // Size needed for array
cin >> n;        // Read in the size
a = new int[n];  // Allocate n ints and save ptr in a.
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    a[i] = 0;    // Initialize all elements to zero.
}
. . .  // Use a as a normal array
delete [] a;  // When done, free memory pointed to by a.
a = NULL;     // Clear a to prevent using invalid memory reference
```

Comment: Don't recommend `new[]` and `delete[]` to people who are new to C++.

Comment: @райтфолд: may I know why? they should start from somewhere... I used to program in borland C++(DOS) version...

Comment: Because they are dangerous tools you never use? Always use `std::vector`.

Comment: @райтфолд: I know how dangerous tools they could be, but our teacher 11 years back likes to work with them, we use to do Video Ram programming during 2nd semester of bachour ;)